# How to get sub total and grand total Based on heading and sub heading in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, grouping

I have this SQL code

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo._SHIFT._SHIFTNAME AS [Shift Name], dbo._TANK._TANKNAME AS [Tank Name],
    dbo._NOZZLE._NOZZLENAME AS [Nozzle Name], 
    dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._OPENING AS Opening, dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._CLOSING AS Closing, 
    SUM(dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._TOTALSALE) AS [Total Sale], 
    dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._RATE AS Rate, 
    CASE
       WHEN GROUPING(dbo._SHIFT._SHIFTNAME) = 1 
          THEN NULL 
       WHEN GROUPING(dbo._TANK._TANKNAME) = 1 
          THEN NULL
       ELSE SUM(dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._TOTALAMOUNT)
    END AS Amount
FROM      
    dbo._NOZZLE 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET ON dbo._NOZZLE._NOZZLEID_PK = dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._NOZZLEID_PK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo._TANK ON dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._TANKID_PK = dbo._TANK._TANKID_PK 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo._SHIFTENTRY ON dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._SHIFTENTRYID_PK = dbo._SHIFTENTRY._SHIFTENTRYID_PK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo._SHIFT ON dbo._SHIFTENTRY._SHIFTID_PK = dbo._SHIFT._SHIFTID_PK
WHERE     
    (dbo._SHIFTENTRY._ISDELETED = N'1') 
    AND (dbo._SHIFT._ISDELETED = N'1') 
    AND (dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._ISDELETED = N'1')
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS  
    ((dbo._SHIFT._SHIFTNAME, dbo._TANK._TANKNAME, dbo._NOZZLE._NOZZLENAME, dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._OPENING, dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._CLOSING, dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET._RATE), (dbo._SHIFT._SHIFTNAME, dbo._TANK._TANKNAME))
```

**Result**

[image]

but I want below result

[image]
[image]

I use `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` , `GROUP BY ROLLUP`, `GROUP BY CUBE` but no luck.

If i Remove GROUP BY and GROUPING SETS Etc. the simple data will be like below

[image]

Excel file Google Drive Link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DgyI_7-p1l7n1KjeAnf1DerQTGLJC-wB

Excel File have 3 Sheets

1. Sample Data, Here the data without groupiung
2. Expected Result
3. Result With GROUPING SETS

Comment: You should simplify the example to make it easier for some other person to understand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done. please have a look

Comment: Yes that is more detail.  Surely you could have a single table with data to represent the problem.

Comment: Provide sample data not screenshots. Also, why have "TOP (100) Percent"?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze `TOP (100) Percent ` was added by SQL Managent studio, may be when I was Ordering

Comment: You need to provide sample data in consumable format not in Excel for instance.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze I was tried to post data here but tabs not proper coming here

Comment: This is way too much. Please minimize the code, sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your grouping sets contain Shiftname and Tankname, so the grouping function will always return 0.

Since the WHERE clause contains criteria for Shift, Shiftentry and Shiftentrydet, the records have to exist, and so the joins are INNER JOINs (ok, maybe not for Tank and Nozzle).

It would be a better idea to group by key values and not by display names, also grouping by additional information (Opening, Closing…) seems to be wrong in my eyes. The only fields that should be grouped are the keys for Shift, Tank and Shiftentrydet (instead of Nozzle, because the Nozzles seem to make up the details), so I would do the grouping and calculation in a subquery (CTE) and join the rest in the main query, although querying the Shiftentrydet and Shift tables twice (once for calculation, once for display). I guess that a column Shiftentrydet_PK does exist).

At last, your query will not return Shift- Tank- and Nozzle-names and headings for the totals in the same column, nor will it create a header row for Shift and Tank. To achieve this, I suggest to use a report (SSRS).

For a query-only non-reporting solution, please try this (not tested):

```
WITH CTE_grp (SHIFTID_PK, TANKID_PK, Shipentrydet_PK, Amount) AS (
    SELECT se._SHIFTID_PK, sed._TANKID_PK, sed.Shipentrydet_PK, SUM(sed._TOTALAMOUNT)
    FROM dbo._SHIFT s
      INNER JOIN dbo._SHIFTENTRY se ON s._SHIFTID_PK = se._SHIFTID_PK
      INNER JOIN dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET sed ON se._SHIFTENTRYID_PK = sed._SHIFTENTRYID_PK
    WHERE (se._ISDELETED = N'1') AND (sed._ISDELETED = N'1') AND (s._ISDELETED = N'1')
    GROUP BY se._SHIFTID_PK, sed._TANKID_PK, sed.Shipentrydet_PK WITH ROLLUP
)
SELECT s._SHIFTNAME AS [Shift Name], t._TANKNAME AS [Tank Name], n._NOZZLENAME AS [Nozzle Name]
  , sed._OPENING AS Opening, sed._CLOSING AS Closing, sed._TOTALSALE AS [Total Sale]
  , sed._RATE AS Rate, c.Amount
FROM CTE_grp c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo._SHIFT s ON c.SHIFTID_PK = s._SHIFTID_PK
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo._TANK t ON c.TANKID_PK = t._TANKID_PK
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo._SHIFTENTRYDET sed ON c.Shipentrydet_PK = sed.Shipentrydet_PK
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo._NOZZLE n ON sed._NOZZLEID_PK = n._NOZZLEID_PK;
```